# Different maven build result from Jenkins than directly

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm setting up Jenkins for an existing maven project. When a build runs, the Jenkins console shows the following error (filenames/URLs changed):

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project: Could not resolve dependencies for project: Failure to find (file jar) in http://example.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]`

When I `cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace` and run `mvn package` myself, the build completes successfully.

I've tried forcing/cleaning, I've tried deleting the Jenkins project and re-adding.

How can I force the build through Jenkins, or what could be causing the cache error?

Comment: Jenkins executes as a different user. Make sure that user has sufficient permissions.

Comment: Permissions to what? It seems to have no complaints about permissions

Comment: I used `su jenkins` and tried the `mvn package` again myself in the jenkins workspace and the build succeeds.

Comment: purge jenkins local maven repository and try again

Comment: It's configured to use ~/.m2 - which I've already purged, is there something else?